# How can I save some terminal commands as a file and run them?

Tags: linux, terminal, shell-script

I am using OpenSuSe 12.3

I want to create a link on my desktop for some specific terminal commands.

The background is that I do some backup via `rsync` and don't want to type the commands every time. I also don't want to use a cronjob, since my computer isn't running all the time.

The perfect solution would be a desktop icon, which on clicking executes the command(s).

Could somebody tell me how to do this?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I want to know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is called a [shell script](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_114/opensuse-reference/cha.adm.shell.html#sec.adm.shellscripts). In its simplest form, this is just a text file with a list of commands that will be run when the file is executed. For example, to run your `rsync` job, create a text file called `rsync.bash` on your desktop and add these lines to it:

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync source target
```

You will, obviously, need to replace that with the actual `rsync` command you want to run. Now, make the file executable:

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/rsync.bash
```

You can now run the `rsync` command by double clicking the text file on your desktop. Depending on how your system is set up, you may be presented with this dialog when you double click:

[image]

Click on either `Run` or `Run in terminal` to execute the script. To run the file without having this dialog pop up, you will need to create a `.desktop` entry for it. Create a file on your desktop called `rsync.desktop` and add these lines to it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Run rsync 
Comment=Rsync script
Exec=/home/user/Desktop/rsync.bash
Icon=/home/user/myicon.gif
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

It should now appear on your desktop using the icon `/home/user/myicon.gif` and you can run it by double clicking. If you want to do this for multiple scripts, standard practice is to create a `$HOME/bin` or `$HOME/scripts` directory, save all your scripts there, and create `.desktop` files calling each script. Just change the `Exec` line above to `Exec=/home/user/scripts/rsync.bash`

Comment: thanx for that helped me alot!